# Trying to define messageId for SQS messages to be placed in S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-sqs

I am trying to use the following lambda code to place a sqs message in a S3 bucket. The code will do that however I need to figure out how to define the messageId so that each object placed in the S3 bucket has the same name as the sqs messageid.

```
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3 = boto3.client("s3")
    data = json.loads(event["Records"][0]["body"])
    s3.put_object(Bucket="dlqbucket", Key="messageId", Body=json.dumps(data))
    
    # TODO implement
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from lambda')
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample incoming record from Amazon SQS to an AWS Lambda function:

```json
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "messageId": "19dd0b57-b21e-4ac1-bd88-01bbb068cb78",
      "receiptHandle": "MessageReceiptHandle",
      "body": "Hello from SQS!",
      "attributes": {
        "ApproximateReceiveCount": "1",
        "SentTimestamp": "1523232000000",
        "SenderId": "123456789012",
        "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp": "1523232000001"
      },
      "messageAttributes": {},
      "md5OfBody": "{{{md5_of_body}}}",
      "eventSource": "aws:sqs",
      "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:sqs:ap-southeast-2:123456789012:MyQueue",
      "awsRegion": "ap-southeast-2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Therefore, you can obtain the `messageId` with:

```
event["Records"][0]["messageId"]
```

[ReceiveMessage Receive Elements @ docs.aws.amazon.com](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ReceiveMessage.html#API_ReceiveMessage_ResponseElements)